# accidentally removed kernel module and don't know how to re enable

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, insmod

i recently had a issue that decreases my internet speed someone told me that i should use a proper driver so i saw a github page where they told to run this command `modprobe -r b43 and more`
b43 in the line means my wifi driver so after that i didn't have internet so i ran another command `modprobe b43` to get it re enabled it worked but after a reboot i have to run the same command to fix the issue also i tried `insmod` it gave me `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /usr/lib/modules/5.9.12-xanmod1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/b43/b43.ko: File exists`
so can someone tell me how to re enable it

DISCLAMER: i have a very bad english typing experience so please bare with me

Comment: See the output of `lsmod | grep b43`. I believe `File exists` means that module is already there. Probably you build another (bad) one and put it somewhere to the _/lib/modules/$VERSION/..._ (_extra_ or alike folder) and that's why you have loaded it instead of the system's one.

Comment: yeah but lsmod | grep b43 it dosn't show anything

Comment: and i used locate it showed /usr/lib/modules/5.9.12-xanmod1/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/b43/b43.ko

Comment: also the file exists changed to Unknown symbol in module and when i enable it it goes back